# How do I change my username?

Tags: discussion

How do I change my username and display profile picture on Stack Overflow?

I can't find the options anywhere. I have tried clicking on my name and display picture, but I can't find the options. I've tried the website and in the app.

Comment: Click on your profile image, reputation, or badges at the top of the screen, then "Edit Profile & Settings," on the upper left.